# Does Visual Studio 2015 support Nuget v1 feeds

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package-restore

I have a v1 Nuget feed from Team City.

I have installed VS 2015.

I am trying to install and existing package and I receive on the find packages the following error

is not a valid NuGet v2 service response

Does VS2015 no longer support V1 feeds? or is there a configuration I can change.

Comment: I am using the v1 Nuget feed from Team City but nothing comes up in packages, no error. :( This is TC 9.1.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got a similar issue with the TeamCity nuget feed.

**To answer your first question, yes, I believe that VS2015 still supports Nuget API V1.**

Here's what I think I know so far:

- TeamCity can use either v1 or v2 of the Nuget API.
- FindPackagesById is implemented in Nuget API v2 not v1 (you can force TeamCity to use v2 by adding a line `teamcity.nuget.api.version=v2` to the `internal.properties` file in the TeamCity Data directory.
- To find out what version you are using you can browse the `$metadata` endpoint on your server (e.g. http://mybuildmachine.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/$metadata). The presence of the `FindPackagesById` method will show you are using v2. The version number in the url doesn't change. Yes, it's confusing.
- TeamCity returns `204 No Content` when `FindPackagesById` returns no packages. Nuget.org returns no results, but wrapped in an XML document.

The source below, in the ASP.NET source is where everything goes wrong. If the XML document from the response cannot be parsed then it just falls over and dies.

https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/37575f3197c0b65d42e3a1db240d636aeab5a1e6/src/Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager/Restore/NuGet/NuGetv2Feed.cs#L230

I couldn't find copies of the Nuget spec to determine what's considered a valid response to `FindPackagesById` but if a `204` response is a violation of the spec then this could be a TeamCity bug.

My current workaround when using multiple packages sources is just to temporarily disable irrelevant sources when installing specific packages.

Comment: This is Teamcity's tracking issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-39211 and the originating github issue: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1759